# Extract data from nested JSON Node JS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, traversal

I need to extract the *text* value of Distance and Duration but unfortunately i haven't been able to traverse the JSON. Any ideas about how to traverse the nodes in Node JS the simplest way possible ?

```
     {
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Chennai, Tamil Nadu, India" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Kolkata, West Bengal, India" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "1,671 km",
                  "value" : 1671269
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "1 day 5 hours",
                  "value" : 104370
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: what've you tried so far? what doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that your JSON is object named data

```
var data =     {
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Chennai, Tamil Nadu, India" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Kolkata, West Bengal, India" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "1,671 km",
                  "value" : 1671269
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "1 day 5 hours",
                  "value" : 104370
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

You would access distance element like this

`data.rows[0].elements[0].distance`

Comment: Great example. Works for me